# How can I create a responsive dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have managed to create a navigation menu that is responsive however on small screen it gets displayed  as per the photo attached. I want to group the links into a drop down menu button that display for small screens.

This is how it's displayed on large screen
[image: This is how it's displayed on large screen]

This is how it's displayed on small screen
[image: This is how it's displayed on small screen]

```
    <header>
<!-- Navigation Links -->    
<div class="overlay"></div> 
          <div class="topnav">
            <nav>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#0" class="active"><div class="image-icon"><img src="img/icons/face_icon.ico" alt="Face Icon"></div>Face</a></li>
                <li><a href="#0"><div class="image-icon"><img src="img/icons/forehead_icon.ico" alt="Forehead Icon"></div>Forehead</a></li>
                <li><a href="#0"><div class="image-icon"><img src="img/icons/eyebrow_icon.ico" alt="Eyebrow Icon"></div>Eyebrow</a></li>
                <li><a href="#0"><div class="image-icon"><img src="img/icons/nose_icon.ico" alt="Nose Icon"></div>Nose</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#0"><div class="image-icon"><img src="img/icons/lip_icon.ico" alt="Lip Icon"></div>Lips</a></li>
                <li><a href="#0"><div class="image-icon"><img src="img/icons/ear_icon.ico" alt="Ear Icon"></div>Ears</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div> <!-- .cd-slider-nav -->
</header>

    .topnav {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.topnav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.topnav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px 30px;
}

.topnav ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 550;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.topnav ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffbb05;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav ul .active {
  color: #ffbb05;
}

.topnav .image-icon img {
    width: 50px;
  }

.topnav .image-icon {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffbb05;
}

.topnav .image-icon:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

    /*
========================================
---------- RESPONSIVE STYLE ------------
========================================
*/
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
 
  .topnav .image-icon img {
    display: none;
  }

  .topnav .image-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Dexter01/vyn3j2d0/

Comment: Check out CSS media queries [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

Comment: Checkout bootstrap - https://getbootstrap.com/, this will help you make responsive websites

Comment: @NikhilSingh Recommending a full framework for a single task like this is unnecessary, and there are other frameworks also. Answers here should be fact-based rather than opinion-based and suggesting one framework when it wasn't even asked about is definitely opinion based!

Comment: @FluffyKitten Yeah I know that obviously, other user already added a media query in the comment so I just added it if the question asker wants to explore, and once someone lands on the website they can obviously go ahead and explore other frameworks too. And the reason for adding bootstrap, just because it's widely used. I didn't mention it as the answer to the question but it can be one of the area question asker wants to explore and learn more about it!

Comment: @NikhilSingh It is still a recommendation that is way beyond the requirements they asked, and it could even be harmful if it sent an inexperienced user off in the wrong direction or into something beyond their level of knowledge, so those sort of suggestions are best kept to users who have expressed an interest in frameworks rather than simple tasks, to keep the information on topic. Even comments should be on-topic too :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten Sure will take care to be more specific next time :)

Comment: Please supply a jsfiddle example

Comment: something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ydapfk3o/26/

Comment: Hi, here is the jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Dexter01/vyn3j2d0/ I have removed the images since I couldn't link it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide the menu when it is on a small screen.
Then you can toggle the visibility for the menu by toggling a class. Something like `is-open`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <!-- Basic Page Needs -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content=" ">
    <meta name="author" content=" ">

    <!-- Mobile Specific Metas -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="mobileoptimized" content="0" />

    <!-- FONT -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@400;500;642;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <header>
    <button class="show">
    Show
    </button>
      <!-- Navigation Links -->
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="topnav">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#0" class="active">
                <div class="image-icon"></div>Face
              </a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">
                <div class="image-icon"></div>Forehead
              </a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">
                <div class="image-icon"></div>Eyebrow
              </a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">
                <div class="image-icon"></div>Nose
              </a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">
                <div class="image-icon"></div>Lips
              </a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">
                <div class="image-icon"></div>Ears
              </a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div> <!-- .cd-slider-nav -->
    </header>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
    </footer>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')

    </script>

    <!-- End Document -->
  </body>

</html>
```

Just added a button with `show` class in the above code block.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {

  .topnav .image-icon img {
    display: none;
  }

  .topnav .image-icon {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .topnav ul {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav ul.is-open {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

Added a media query only for handling the menu in small screen size.

```
$(".show").click(() => {
    $(".topnav ul").toggleClass("is-open");
})
```

Jquery code for toggling the class.

I prefer this, to using normal `show() and hide()`, This way you can change all descendants of the `is-open` class.
Here is the modified [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lsrawat/d64yfeLk/4/)